# Angular 2 / Ionic 2 - input box focus function doesn't exist

Tags: angular, focus, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app, I have a page that has a button on it. When you press the button it brings up a Modal screen with an input box on it. When the Modal page opens up, I want to focus the cursor on the input box on the Modal page so the user can start typing immediately.

In my Modal page, I have the following HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input #search type="text" placeholder="Type an area e.g. Bedroom" [value]="searchValue" [formControl]="inputSearchControl"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

In my code I have the following:

```
    @ViewChild("search") inputBox;

    ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.inputBox.nativeElement.focus();

    this.inputSearchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe((callbackText) => {
        this.selectedArray = this.originalArrayBeforeAnyFiltering.filter((item) => {
            return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(callbackText.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        });
    });
}
```

So after the **View** has initialised, focus the cursor on the input box on the modal. But when my code runs on the **View** initialising, it fails due to the function not existing:

`VM415:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.inputBox.focus is not a function(…)`

On the console it says that *focus* is an *EventEmitter* but I'm not sure how to use this to achieve what I'm wanting.

Any help would be appreciated.

bengrah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setFocus()` function.

```
this.inputBox.setFocus()
```

Source [this discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/setting-focus-to-an-input-in-ionic-2/62789)

Also according to [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/input/Input/), `focus` is an output event of `ion-input`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - that's worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @suraj this thing is not working for me. in my <ion-input>