# how to make set focus to any input field in ionic 2?

Tags: forms, validation, ionic-framework, ionic2, setfocus

In my ionic2 application, I have a textbox , now i am submitting the form without add any value in that textbox , at that time i have give an alert that 'the textbox can not be empty'.
now when alert get close focus should be in same texbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576869/angular-2-ionic-2-input-box-focus-function-doesnt-exist/42577709#42577709

Comment: thanks @suraj i'll go thruogh it

Comment: can you add your code?

Answer (score 2):

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('input') myInput ;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) { }

  ionViewLoaded() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myInput.setFocus();
    },150);

 }

}
```

1) import "Input", "ViewChild" and "NavController"

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
```

2) Create a reference to your input in your template :

```
<ion-input #input>
@ViewChild('input') myInput ;
```

3) Trigger the focus

```
ionViewLoaded() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myInput.setFocus();
    },150);

 }
```

4) Show the keyboard

add this line to your config.xml :

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Comment: Why do you need a timeout, is there any more elegant way of using the correct lifecycle?